# 2D transient heat equation solution

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, heat-equation

I want to calculate the time- and space- dependent temperature of a 2D system where there are 3 materials, with different thermal properties.
The system can be described by the schematics:

```
MoltenFilm = Rectangle[{-4, 0}, {4, 2}];
centers = {{-2, 0}, {2, 0}};
Fib = RegionUnion[Disk[#, 1] & /@ centers];
Inter = RegionDifference[MoltenFilm, Fib];
RegionPlot[{Fib, Inter}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Actually, the system is periodic in the x direction. So one could just use this as repeat unit:

[image]

The thermal properties of the materials are are:

```
(*k is in W/mK; rho in Kg/m3; Cp in J/(kgK)*)
ka = 0.024; rhoa = 1.292; Cpa = 1003;   (*white area*)
kf = 0.33; rhof = 940; Cpf = 2100;      (*orange area*)
kr = 0.22; rhor = 1300; Cpr = 1300;     (*blue area*)
```

The initial condition of the system is (T is homogeneous inside each domain):

```
Tblue=40;
Twhite=20;
Torange=220;
```

As for boundary conditions, I am looking for:

- Neumann boundary condition at the white-orange interface (y=0)
- Neumann boundary condition at the white-orange interface (y=2)
- Flux continuity at the orange-blue interface

Help in setting this up is appreciated.

Comment: Is this just theoretical question or solution also needed?

Comment: Hi, I know the theoretical elements of this transport phenomena problem. I am looking for an implementation in Mathematica 12.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can solve this problem with Mathematica FEM as follows

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

(*k is in W/mK;rho in Kg/m3;Cp in J/(kgK)*)ka = 0.024; rhoa = 1.292; \
Cpa = 1003;   (*white area*)
kf = 0.33; rhof = 940; Cpf = 2100;      (*orange area*)
kr = 0.22; rhor = 1300; Cpr = 1300;     (*blue area*)

reg1 = Disk[{2, 0}, 1]; reg2 = 
 RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {4, 2}], reg1];  reg = 
 Rectangle[{0, -1}, {4, 2}]; mesh = 
 ToElementMesh[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> 1/400];
Show[mesh["Wireframe"], Graphics[{{Opacity[0.5], Blue, reg1}}], 
 Graphics[{{Opacity[.25], Orange, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {4, 2}]}}]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

```
k[x_, y_] := 
 If[Element[{x, y}, reg2], kf, If[Element[{x, y}, reg1], kr, ka]]; 
rho[x_, y_] := 
 If[Element[{x, y}, reg2], rhof, 
  If[Element[{x, y}, reg1], rhor, rhoa]]; 
cp[x_, y_] := 
 If[Element[{x, y}, reg2], Cpf, If[Element[{x, y}, reg1], Cpr, Cpa]]; 
T0[x_, y_] := 
 If[Element[{x, y}, reg2], Torange, 
  If[Element[{x, y}, reg1], Tblue, Twhite]]

eq = Inactivate[
   cp[x, y] rho[x, y] D[T[x, y, t], t] - 
    Div[k[x, y] Grad[T[x, y, t], {x, y}], {x, y}], D | Div | Grad];

sol = NDSolve[{Activate[eq] == 0, T[x, y, 0] == T0[x, y]}, T, 
  Element[{x, y}, mesh], {t, 0, 10000}]
```

Visualization

```
Table[DensityPlot[Evaluate[T[x, y, t] /. sol[[1]]], 
  Element[{x, y}, mesh], ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t}]], {t, 0, 10000, 2000}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

**Update 1.** In a case convection heart transfer on the air-solid interface the code should be modified as follows

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

(*k is in W/mK;rho in Kg/m3;Cp in J/(kgK)*)ka = 0.024; rhoa = 1.292; \
Cpa = 1003;   (*white area*)
kf = 0.33; rhof = 940; Cpf = 2100;      (*orange area*)
kr = 0.22; rhor = 1300; Cpr = 1300;     (*blue area*)

Tblue = 40;
Twhite = 20;
Torange = 220;

reg1 = Disk[{2, 0}, 1]; reg2 = 
 RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {4, 2}], reg1]; reg = 
 RegionUnion[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {4, 2}], reg1]; mesh = 
 ToElementMesh[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> 1/400];
k[x_, y_] := If[Element[{x, y}, reg2], kf, kr]; 
rho[x_, y_] := If[Element[{x, y}, reg2], rhof, rhor]; 
cp[x_, y_] := If[Element[{x, y}, reg2], Cpf, Cpr]; 
T0[x_, y_] := If[Element[{x, y}, reg2], Torange, Tblue];

eq1 = cp[x, y] rho[x, y] D[T[x, y, t], t] - 
   Div[k[x, y] Grad[T[x, y, t], {x, y}], {x, y}];

h = 10^3; sol = 
 NDSolve[{eq1 == NeumannValue[h (Twhite - T[x, y, t]), y <= 0], 
   T[x, y, 0] == T0[x, y]}, T, Element[{x, y}, mesh], {t, 0, 10000}];
```

Visualization

```
Table[DensityPlot[Evaluate[T[x, y, t] /. sol[[1]]], 
  Element[{x, y}, mesh], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t}]], {t, 0, 10000, 2000}]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: How can I identify the interface between the orange and white domain? I would like to test what happens when I fix the heat flux level over that interface, eg h*(Torange-Twhite), while the flux at the orange-blue interface remains unlimited.

Comment: @Luigi Do you mean that in the air region we have some convection flow?

Comment: yes. The heat exchange between the orange material and the white material (air) can be affected by convection. So I was thinking of simulating also the case where, over that interface, the flux is fixed. How to identify the interface?

Comment: @Luigi This question is not trivial. It could be better to open new topic for discussion new problem with air-body interface. Also if you can show gravitational force, then we can compute convection as well.

Comment: in my opinion, the 'convection' effect can be included in the calculation of the heat exchange constant h (flux=h*DT). No need to calculate the detailed convection pattern.

Comment: No, it is not right. In this geometry we can't predict `h` without flow computation.

Comment: I see your point. But suppose we calculate h with modelling of the detailed convection flow, how do you set the flux value over the interface of the two mediums?

Comment: @Luigi Do you mean that we can neglect by air-flow and therefore can describe air temperature as a given value?

Comment: Actually I am not interested in the T distribution in the air. Therefore, as you say, we can take an average value and describe the flux as hDT. But i miss how to write this BC on a line in your 2D formulation.

Comment: @Luigi It looks like airflow should be 3D with main stream that orthogonal to the 2D region where we compute temperature.  Can we also apply `h` to the air-blue region interface?

Comment: yes! heat is also exchanged at the air-blue fiber interface. Therefore, it is correct to fix the flux level (h*DT) also over that interface.

Comment: Please, see Update 1 to my answer.