# BarLegend inconsistent with DensityPlot colors

Tags: plotting, color, legending

In this post, [2D transient heat equation solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285757/2d-transient-heat-equation-solution/285790?noredirect=1#comment711846_285790), @Alex Trounev helped me, in setting up a 2D simulation of a heat transfer problem where multiple materials are involved. The code is here:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]


(*mesh*)
fibdiam = 0.06;   
fibrad = fibdiam/2;
time1=0.8;

reg1 = Disk[{0, 0}, fibrad];   
reg2 = RegionDifference[
   Rectangle[{-2*fibrad, 0}, {2*fibrad, 2*fibrad}], reg1];  
reg = RegionUnion[Rectangle[{-2*fibrad, 0}, {2*fibrad, 2*fibrad}], 
   reg1];  
mesh1 = ToElementMesh[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> fibdiam/10000];

(*material parameters*)
kf = 0.33; rhof = 940; Cpf = 2100;
kr = 0.22; rhor = 1300; Cpr = 1300;

k[x_, y_] := (10^6)*If[Element[{x, y}, reg2], kf, kr];
rho[x_, y_] := If[Element[{x, y}, reg2], rhof, rhor];
cp[x_, y_] := If[Element[{x, y}, reg2], Cpf, Cpr];

(*initial condition*)

TfibNW = 40;
TairNW = 40;
Tmelt = 220;

T01[x_, y_] := If[Element[{x, y}, reg2], Tmelt,If[Element[{x, y}, reg1], TfibNW, TairNW]]

(*solving PDE*)

eq1 = cp[x, y] rho[x, y] D[T1[x, y, t], t] - 
   Div[k[x, y] Grad[T1[x, y, t], {x, y}], {x, y}];

ic = T1[x, y, 0] == T01[x, y];
bc1 = NeumannValue[(10^-3)*h*(T1[x, y, t] - TairNW)/kr, y <= 0];
bc2 = NeumannValue[(10^-3)*h*(T1[x, y, t] - TairNW)/kf, y >= 2*fibrad];

h = 10^3;

 sol1 = 
 NDSolve[{eq1 == bc1 + bc2, ic}, T1, 
  Element[{x, y}, mesh1], {t, 0, time1}];


(*2D plotting*)

Table[
 
 Show[DensityPlot[Evaluate[T1[x, y, t] /. sol1[[1]]], 
   Element[{x, y}, mesh1],
   ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap",
   PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Automatic, {0, 250}}],
   PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 250}},
   AspectRatio -> Automatic,
   PlotPoints -> 100,
   MaxRecursion -> 2,
   ImageSize -> 250,
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t}]],
  
  Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, fibrad]]],
 
 {t, 0, time1, time1/5}]
```

This leads to the following 2D graphs:

[image]

What I noticed is that the scale bar and the actual values of `T1[x, y, t] /. sol1[[1]]]` are inconsistent. This is obvious when I plot a cross section of the DensityPlot that is temperature at a fixed `x` coordinate (eg `x==0`) as function of time.

Is this a bug? How to fix it?

For 1D temperature profiles vertical through the center of the disk:

```
(*1D Temp profiles*)

Show[Table[
  Plot[Evaluate[T1[0, y, t] /. sol1[[1]]], {y, -fibrad, 2*fibrad},
   PlotRange -> {{-2*fibrad, 2*fibrad}, All},
   GridLines -> {{-fibrad, fibrad}, None},
   GridLinesStyle -> Red,
   Frame -> True,
   Axes -> None],
  
  {t, 0, time1, time1/5}]]
```

[image]

the temperature, at long times (close to `time1`) should be 160 in all the mesh points, but this is not consistent with the corresponding 2D image (3rd image, 2nd row).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found some help in this post:
[Why does PlotRange in DensityPlot have no effect](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82947/why-does-plotrange-in-densityplot-have-no-effect). A way out is to rescale the ColorFunction:

```
Table[Show[
  DensityPlot[Evaluate[T1[x, y, t] /. sol1[[1]]], 
   Element[{x, y}, mesh1],
   PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {20, 230}},
   PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Automatic, {20, 230}}],
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Rescale[#, {20, 230}]] &),
   AspectRatio -> Automatic,
   PlotPoints -> 100,
   MaxRecursion -> 2,
   ImageSize -> 250,
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t}]],
  
  Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, fibrad]]], {t, 0, time1, time1/5}]
```

Other views are also appreciated.